# Slow response times in browser in rails 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, thin

I am running a rails 4.2.2 app with thin as server.
In production mode the log shows that the render times are pretty fine:

```
> I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.234241 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered partials/_full_map.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.234548 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered partials/_date_picker.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.234983 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered partials/_resorts_filter.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.240087 #44391]  INFO -- : 
Read fragment views/there/3c482c445a6cf61ee40c95ee5d1d0147 (4.9ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.247775 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered partials/_date_modal.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.247865 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered resorts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.6ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.249438 #44391]  INFO -- :   
Rendered partials/_header.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2015-10-19T20:55:50.250012 #44391]  INFO -- : 
Completed 200 OK in 133ms (Views: 16.9ms | ActiveRecord: 14.6ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

But the chrome network tab tells me something totally different and this how it also feels like, very slow

```
?lastSnow=0 GET 200 document    Other   135 KB  638 ms
```

How does it come that there is such a huge difference and how can I identify the bottleneck?
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your server doesn't know how much time your files spend traveling across the network, or how long it takes to render your Javascript, CSS, etc. on your browser. I've been reading a lot of the articles on Nate Berkopec's blog, which have helped me wrap my mind around page load performance.  http://www.nateberkopec.com/